# PHP block file from reading

Tags: php, fopen, fread, flock

I am trying a simple algorithm which says:

File1: (lock.php)

- Open a File
- Lock the File, so that no other PHP file can read this
- Sleep
- Release Lock

File2: (lockstatus.php)

- Try to open the file.
- If not opening

  - Wait for Lock to release
- Else

  - Read the file

My code implementation:

**Lock.php**:

```
<?php
$f = fopen("key",'a');
if (flock($f, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    echo "File Locked. For Next 60 Seconds\n";
    sleep(60);
    var_dump(flock($f, LOCK_UN)); //release lock
    echo "lock released";
} else {
    echo "blocked";
}
?>
```

**Lockstatus.php**

```
<?php
do {
    echo "\n";
    $f = fopen("key",'a');
    if ($f) {
        echo "Readable\n";
        fclose ($f);
    } else {
        echo "Blocked! I am waiting\n";
        sleep(10);
    }
} while (!$f); //wait until fopen does not work
?>
```

**Problem:**
*Even, `flock` is applied, the `Lockstatus.php` is able to open the file.*

**Question:**

How to block the file reading at `Lockstatus.php` once it is locked by `Lock.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `flock()` only provides advisory locking. The other program may completely ignore this and proceed to fopen and fread or whatever else. The key is to use `flock` in your Lockstatus.php as well after your do the `fopen` to check if there are existing locks. `flock` in Lockstatus.php would fail and then you would know there is an existing lock.

Answer (score 1):

This function flock() has different behavior on linux and windows.

Take a deep look at "Notes" on PHP docs. This might be your issue.

[flock on PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

After that, pay attention on r+ parameter, it´s mandatory for reading+locking.

```
$fp = fopen('/tmp/lock.txt', 'r+');
```

It wont work with **a**.

Comment: I am using Linux. Therefore, I guess it should work in my case. And made it 'r+' however, it does not work .

Comment: Take a look at the first comment on docs: "The flock function follows the semantics of the Unix system call bearing the same name. Flock utilizes ADVISORY locking only; that is, other processes may ignore the lock completely; it only affects those that call the flock call."